# CodeIgniter website redirect to localhost after migrating online server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just uploaded my application on my hosting account, the account is provided by `hostinger`. You can see the link [here](http://primodebug.esy.es/Calendario/).

**Configuration file:**

```
<?php
class SystemConfiguration {
// General Settings
public static $base_url    = 'http://primodebug.esy.es/Calendario/';
// Database Settings
public static $db_host     = 'mysql.hostinger.it';
public static $db_name     = 'u460105738_primo';
public static $db_username = 'u460105738_ferve';
public static $db_password = '*****';
```

[CodeIgniter config.php file](http://pastebin.com/Eyg6dpkH) (It's too long to paste here).

**.HTACCESS**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I also have other problems logging probably related files .httaccess I have no idea, but it seems that some javascript files are not loaded properly. What can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First place to look is in /application/config/config.php where the item `$config['base_url']` should be set to your hosting account.

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://primodebug.esy.es/';
```

If that is set as shown then you have hard-coded 'localhost' elsewhere in your code.

In this example Codeigniter's "URL Helper" will need to be loaded before loading SystemConfiguration. So run `$this->load->helper('url');` somewhere before loading SystemConfiguration. Or, it can be done in the constructor of SystemConfiguration like this.

```
<?php
class SystemConfiguration {
// General Settings
public static $base_url;
// Database Settings
public static $db_host     = 'mysql.hostinger.it';
public static $db_name     = 'u460105738_primo';
public static $db_username = 'u460105738_ferve';
public static $db_password = '*****';
}

function __construct()
{
  $this->CI->load->helper('url');
  $this->base_url = base_url('Calendario/')
}
```

Comment: All the url is correct.. I suspect that I should edit the .htaccess file with some settings, but I don't know how edit this file, could help me maybe..?

Comment: Your .htaccess knows nothing about localHost so there is no reason for it to add that to the server request. The browser shows the requested url as "http://localhost/Calendario/user/login"  So somewhere in your code something is adding "localhost" to your URLs. If config.php is set then the problem maybe in routes.php or even your javascript.

Comment: When I've reuploaded the file the link working well and don't redirect to localhost, after some minutes the problem's back. In my code there's no localhost references.. I'm using the $base_url variable to connect each part of code.